# Set margin between label and input in HTML form

Tags: html, forms, margin

I want to change the margin between the label and input of a simple HTML form. The labels are below the input fields. When I set a class I can change other properties like font-size but not margin.

Comment: You're going to need to post some code.

Comment: can you provide us with a JsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yanchun/fYM8h/

Comment: Don't get confused by the down votes and the comments asking for code. Your question is just fine for a beginner and doesn't really need any code if one understands the CSS box model. See my answer (and gave you an upvote for your question).

Answer (score 18):

A `<label>` is displayed as `inline` by default. You have to change that to `inline-block` or `block` in order to set the `margin`.

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Some resources to learn more about the CSS box model:

- [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model)
- [CSS-Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/)

Some resources to learn more about the `display` attribute in CSS:

- [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Answer (score 2):

you can't set margin top and bottom for , because  tag is called as inline element, if u need to set margin top or bottom,then change to block element like below codes

```
label {
        margin: 10px 0px;
        display: block;
}
```

or

```
label {
            margin: 10px 0px;
            float: left;
    }
```

If you add css "Float:left" for any element , then tat will changed as block element

Answer (score 0):

Think of spans and text to be inline. In-line elements must be turned block in order to use a margin. Also making it block means if the label is too big it can push content down.